# How can the ordered triple (a,b,c) be equivalent to the ordered pair (a,(b,c))?

Tags: linear-algebra

In what sense and in which field it is true? 
I mean, intuitively, the aforementioned 2 terms seems unequal.

PS-
I don't know what more it takes to meet the quality standards on SE. The question can't be completed without PS.

Comment: What is meant by "equivalent"?

Comment: You can check it applying the definition: [Defining the ordered pair using set theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_pair#Defining_the_ordered_pair_using_set_theory).

Comment: That downvote seems wrong to me - it's a perfectly reasonable question. Of course as stated the question is formally meaningless, because the definition of "equivalent" is missing. But that's just because the OP doesn't know our language. Seems clear to me what the OP is really wondering about; what he wants to know is the answer to the qiestion that we would state as "In what sense is $(a,b,c)$ equivalent to $(a,(b,c))$?"

Comment: What is meant by "SE"?

Comment: @Jacopo: Presumably *Stack Exchange*.

Comment: @ankit Questions *can* be completed without "post scriptum", but presumably the site has an automatic check of minimum length for quetions (one-liners rarely make good posts, be it answers or questions). For instance, instead of writing down that stuff, you could have used that space to prevent some of the clarification requests you've received.

Answer (score 4):

Of course the question is a little fuzzy without a definition of "equivalent". Since it seems likely that no such definition will be forthcoming in this context, someone might say this:

The only important thing about ordered triples is that $(a,b,c)=(a',b',c')$ if and only if $a'=a$, $b'=b$ and $c'=c$. If we *defined* $(a,b,c)$ by $(a,b,c)=(a,(b,c))$ then this property would follow. So if we feel like it we can define $(a,b,c)$ that way and everything will work the way it should.

Answer (score 1):

They are equivalent in the sense, that for sets $A,B$ and $C$ we have:
$$A \times B \times C \cong A \times (B\times C)$$

meaning there is a bijection $i : A \times B \times C \to A \times (B\times C)$ turning $(a,b,c)$ into $(a,(b,c))$ and this is the only "natural" or "canonical" bijection you can think of.

Remark: "Natural bijection" has a precise meaning, which is explored in the field of category theory, but knowing this is not *really* necessary to understand this example.